# Formatting array before send back to client

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json, vb.net, web-services

Try to put as detail as possible on my problem. Below are my code.

```
<script>
    var dealers = new Array();
    dealers.push(new Array("123", "870503-23-5370", "021"));
    dealers.push(new Array("456", "830503-23-5371", "031"));
    dealers.push(new Array("789", "870103-11-5372", "041"));
    dealers.push(new Array("654", "870501-23-5373", "051"));
    dealers.push(new Array("321", "880503-12-5374", "061"));
    dealers.push(new Array("987", "870803-23-5375", "071"));
    dealers.push(new Array("109", "870508-06-5376", "081"));
    dealers.push(new Array("174", "810503-03-5377", "091"));
    dealers.push(new Array("509", "870103-01-5378", "101"));
    dealers.push(new Array("687", "870501-12-5379", "131"));

    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "DailyCheck.asmx/DailyCheckDealer",
                data: JSON.stringify({ records: dealers }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: onSuccess,
                failure: onError
            });         
        });
    })

    function onSuccess(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
    function onError() {
        alert("fail");
    }
</script>
```

**DailyCheck.asmx**

```
Public Class DailyCheck
    Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

    Public Class Dealer
        Public IDNo, ICFound, POFound As String
    End Class

    <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function DailyCheckDealer(records As String()()) As List(Of Dealer)
    Dim mylist As List(Of String()) = records.ToList()
    Dim datarow As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To mylist.Count - 1
        Dim m As String() = mylist(i)
        For j As Integer = 0 To m.Length - 1
            datarow += m(j) + " "
            result = datarow
        Next
    Next

    ' Insert the array into the database.

    Dim myConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Conn")
    Dim myConnection1 = New SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim myCommand = New SqlCommand()
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection1
    myCommand.CommandText = "DailyCheckDealer"
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRow", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Value = datarow
    myConnection1.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection1.Close()

    Dim myConnection2 = New SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim objComm As New SqlCommand("Select IDNo, IDFound, POFound From DailyDealerCheck Order By IDNo", myConnection2)
    Dim dealerList As New List(Of Dealer)()
    myConnection2.Open()
    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = objComm.ExecuteReader()
    While sdr.Read()
        Dim objDealer As New Dealer()
        objDealer.IDNo = sdr("IDNo").ToString()
        objDealer.ICFound = sdr("IDFound").ToString()
        objDealer.POFound = sdr("POFound").ToString()
        dealerList.Add(objDealer)
    End While
    Return dealerList
End Function
```

**Firebug: Post value:**

> {"records":[["123","870503-23-5370","021"],["456","830503-23-5371","031"],["789","870103-11-5372","041"
>   ],["654","870501-23-5373","051"],["321","880503-12-5374","061"],["987","870803-23-5375","071"],["109"
>   ,"870508-06-5376","081"],["174","810503-03-5377","091"],["509","870103-01-5378","101"],["687","870501-12-5379"
>   ,"131"]]}

**MSSQL: Select result:**

[image]

From above code gave me since it using alert(); :

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

**Firebug: Response value are:**

> {"d":[{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"109","ICFound":"0","POFound":"0"},{"__type"
>   :"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"123","ICFound":"1","POFound":"1"},{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer
>   .DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"174","ICFound":"0","POFound":"0"},{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck
>   +Dealer","IDNo":"321","ICFound":"0","POFound":"0"},{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo"
>   :"456","ICFound":"0","POFound":"1"},{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"509","ICFound"
>   :"0","POFound":"0"},{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"654","ICFound":"0","POFound"
>   :"1"},{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"687","ICFound":"0","POFound":"0"},{"__type"
>   :"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"789","ICFound":"0","POFound":"0"},{"__type":"DailyCheckDealer
>   .DailyCheck+Dealer","IDNo":"987","ICFound":"0","POFound":"0"}]}

**My question:**

1. How to remove `"__type":"DailyCheckDealer.DailyCheck+Dealer"` from array as return value.
2. How to format the array into this format as return value:

> {"response":[["123","1","1"],["456","0","0"],["789","0","0"],["654","0","1"],["321","1","0"],["987","0","1"],["109","0","0"],["174","1","0"],["509","0","0"],["687","1","0"]]}

**Expected return value from webservice:**

```
<Dealer>
    <IDNo>123</IDNo>
    <IcFound>0</IcFound>
    <POFound>1</POFound>
</Dealer>
<Dealer>
    <IDNo>456</IDNo>
    <IcFound>1</IcFound>
    <POFound>1</POFound>
</Dealer>
...........
```